# index on two columns with one key value

Tags: mysql, sql, indexing

I have a table with two time fields (and other fields): dateX and dateY.

I want to be able to sort the rows so that if a dateX is not null, we use that row's dateX for ordering and if dateX is null we use the row's dateY for ordering.

Is there a way to optimize the schema, index these columns, etc. so that this can be done efficiently without de-normalizing the rows by adding a column that is combination of the two dates(if dateX != null : dateX ? dateY )?

Comment: Why not using two distinct indexes for each date column?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use MySQL's [`IFNULL()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_ifnull) function:

```
ORDER BY IFNULL(dateX, dateY)
```

However, note that such a sorting operation will not benefit from any indexes that you have defined on your table—and may therefore be slow.

The only way that an index can help with this sort is if, as you suggest, you denormalise the table and store the precomputed result of this operation in its own (indexed) column.  You could, if so desired, define `BEFORE INSERT` and `BEFORE UPDATE` [triggers](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/triggers.html) to ensure that such a column remains consistent with the underlying data:

```
CREATE TRIGGER myTable_bi BEFORE INSERT ON myTable FOR EACH ROW
  SET NEW.dateCombined = IFNULL(NEW.dateX, NEW.dateY);

CREATE TRIGGER myTable_bu BEFORE UPDATE ON myTable FOR EACH ROW
  SET NEW.dateCombined = IFNULL(NEW.dateX, NEW.dateY);
```

Comment: How will this use of the `IFNULL()` function make use of a single index with the two dates?

Comment: ORDER BY IFNULL(dateX, dateY) is helpful knowledge if performance wasn't an issue and the triggers certainly make this simpler than adding non-sql code to enforce the consistency. are those two triggers the only ones necessary - are there any edge-case changes to worry about?

Comment: @lf215: I'm pretty sure that those triggers would cover all possibilities, except any preexisting data which can be handled with an initial `UPDATE myTable SET dateCombined = IFNULL(dateX, dateY)`.